# Laravel - method whereDate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, sum

So in this project I have homepage which is showing only posts that are made that day. And right now I need my price summing for that day and for that I add this to my price summing code

In my `home.blade.php` for summing price :

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>
    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
    <th>GOTOVINA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Gotovina')->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
    <th>VIRMAN:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Virman')->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
    <th>NK:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'NK')->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

And this `whereDate` method is from my `HomeController` and here it is:

```
public function index()
{
    $date = new Carbon(request('date'));

    $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(30); //add {{ $posts->links() }} if paginate is enabled
    return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

And my route in `web.php` is:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And all it returns me is that method whereDate does not exist. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The error is in your view you forgot brackets after each `->posts`:  you should use `Auth::user()->posts()->...`

Comment: To get the user id, try `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: Yes I forgot brackets.. That's what you get when panic.. Thank you dude.
And I have another question if you can help me please, should I post a new question or we can do it here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you use some lines with:

```
Auth::user()->posts->where...
```

Consider that `Auth::user()->posts` returns a `collection` of user *posts* but `Auth::user()->posts()` returns a `query builder` instance.

Luckly laravel `collection` has the `where()` method defined but it has not the `whereDate()` method, instead this is defined on the `query builder`, so in your view you have to use this line:

```
Auth::user()->posts()->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')
```

Comment: I fixed it , thank you very much for your time and explaining this to me!

Comment: I have one more question, should I make a new question post ?

Comment: It's better so we'll leave this question clean

Comment: I agree, I will make another question in a second !

Comment: Ouch, I need to wait for the second question, just one question in 90 minutes you know...